# Changing T flipflop to D

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

For a recent examn, i was asked to create a counter, that counted backwards from 15-1 then starting over from 15, in odd numbers. I did so with a T flipflop, and the following question was for me to implement the same thing, with a D flipflop.
In my answer i just added an xor gate to the input, and made the flipflop to a D one.

Comment: I believe your thinking is backwards. That's how you get from D to T. You would likely need to draw a K-Map to help you convert from T to D.

Comment: To make a D FF work as T FF, and both as /2 counter connect D to Q'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This would probably be the schematic for the whole thing, for reference. Attach inverters to all the outputs to make the counter count backwards. Anyway, just connect Q(the output) to the input D with an XOR gate to make a D flip flop out of a T flop.